# what is the point of sexp_of_opaque?

Tags: ocaml

In [ppxlib](https://v3.ocaml.org/p/ppxlib/0.21.0/doc/Stdppx/index.html) it says that

> sexp_of_opaque x converts the value x of opaque type to an S-expression. This means the user need not provide converters, but the result cannot be interpreted.

Does it mean I can call this on any types? But what is the point if I cannot do anything with it?

Comment: If you're quoting something, can you provide a link to the entire page?

Comment: markdown was broken, fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converter `sexp_of_opaque` matches any value of any type to `<opaque>`.

It can be useful to represent holes in the sexp representation or when using the `base` or `core` library to have a placeholder function for `sexp` conversion when such function is expected in a functor argument.

Comment: I see! So when it's required, and I need to provide one, but I don't care about how it's used because I'll never use it